# acts_as_votable NoMethodError (undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, voting-system

I'm trying to implement voting on comments within pits in my app and I keep getting a no method error. I've tried rearranging my code a number of different ways to get it to work but its not cooperating. My error in terminal shows this

```
Parameters: {"pit_id"=>"1", "comment_id"=>"2"}
  Pit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pits".* FROM "pits"  WHERE "pits"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:22:in `upvote'
```

Its finding the "pit id" and the "comment id" but something is clearly a bit off. Would somebody with a better understanding of whats going on to point out what that it is. Thanks.

As it is now my code

_comment.html.erb

```
<div class = "well">
    <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
    <p>posted by: <%= comment.user.name %></p>
       <%= link_to "Upvote", pit_comment_like_path(@pit, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
       <%= link_to "Downvote", pit_comment_dislike_path(@pit, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%if comment.user == current_user %>

     <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [@pit, comment],
                 method: :delete,
                 data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>             
  </p>
  </div>


Comments Controller

class CommentsController < ApplicationController


 def create
  @pit= Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.build(comments_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save

  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

  def destroy
    @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
    @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

def upvote
  @comment = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.upvote_by current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

def downvote
  @comment = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.downvote_by current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get 'users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    match 'users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user', via: 'get'
  end

  resources :pits do
    resources :comments do
      put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
    end
  end





  root to: 'pages#home'
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
end
```

User Class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  has_many :pits
  has_many :comments
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  def name
    name = first_name + ' ' + last_name
  end


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,


 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment Class

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :pit
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: You didn't initialized `@pit` in your `upvote` method,so it is `nil` in this line `@comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])` which gives you that error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I put in my upvote method -  @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.upvote_by current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)

I get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment without an ID):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:22:in `upvote'

in my terminal.

Comment: So I passed :comment_ID in "@comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])" and its now recording my votes BUT I'm getting a template error in terminal that says "Started PUT "/pits/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-21 11:07:23 -0500
Processing by PitsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms".